# How can I get one record from related model by specific value having HAS_MANY relation

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-model

I use Yii2. There are two models which are related by

> hasMany

method, for example Users and UsersArticles:

```
public function getUsersArticles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UsersArticles::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Is there some way to get only one related record by id? Something like that:

```
$User->usersArticles[$id]->someMethodFromUsersArticles();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `ActiveQuery` and write something like that:

```
$articles = $user->getUserArticles()->id($id)->one();
```

or just

```
$articles = $user->getUserArticles()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```